# How can I split keys of dictionary values using the comma?

Tags: python, dictionary

The dictionary value mentioned below

```
dict = {'Incident, INC': 'Incident',
 'SR, Service Request': 'Service Request',
 'RCA ticket, Task': 'Problem',
 'OCM, Alert': 'Change',
 'Change': 'Minor enhancements'}
```

I need to map the dictionary values this

```
expect dictionary  = {
      'INC': 'Incident',  
      'Incident': 'Incident',
      'Inc': 'Incident', 
      'Change': 'Minor Enchancement',
      'SR': 'ServiceRequest',
      'ServiceRequest': 'ServiceRequest'
}
```

I need to add more one condition given dictionary would the read given list if any of the value match it should the dict value or else it should return like `Unspecified`.

input ---->

```
new_list= ['Incident','INC','SR','Change','ABC']
```

Expected output --->

```
new_list = ['Incident','Incident','Minor Enchancement','Service Request','others']
```

My code does not work.

```
reversed_dict = {}
for key in my_dict:
    items = [x.strip() for x in my_dict[key].split()]
    for i in items:
        reversed_dict[i] = key
```

Comment: Your logic behind splitting is not clear for me. Where does `'Inc': 'Incident',` with lower `nc` come from?

Comment: Hi @S.B         This word should be nc should be in upper case

Comment: So please edit the question and correct the mistakes.

Comment: Hi @S.B    I need the split the key of dictionary using comma for example if dict contains like this  dict = {'Incident, INC': 'Incident'}  i need to assign dict like this new_dict=  {'Incident : 'Incident', 'INC':'Incident'}

Comment: Check the answer. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
rdict = {}

for key in dict:
    if any(list(map(lambda char: char in key, ','))):
        k = key.split(',')
    else: k = [key]

    for i in k:
        rdict[i.strip()] = dict[key]

print (rdict)
```

Returns:

```
{' Alert': 'Change',
 ' INC': 'Incident',
 ' Service Request': 'Service Request',
 ' Task': 'Problem',
 'Change': 'Minor enhancements',
 'Incident': 'Incident',
 'OCM': 'Change',
 'RCA ticket': 'Problem',
 'SR': 'Service Request'}
```

Comment: Did you forgot to also strip the keys?

Comment: Whoops, I didnt even notice the whitespace until now. Ah well strip can easily be added.